# make Clang-Format ignore comments for line break

Tags: c++, clang, clang-format, autoformatting

Is it possible to tell Clang-Format to ignore comments for line break operations? The idea is to follow the style "the code is well formatted, even if comments exceed the line break margin". Code should not be split in multiple lines, if it does not exceed the margin, but the comment does.

e.g.

```
//desired behaviour:
short code = shortCode + 
        longlonglongCode;
short code = shortCode; //long comment without a line break

//not desired behaviour:
short code =
    shortCode;  //long comment without a line break
```

Comment: Did you ever found a solution for this?

Comment: @XKpe unfortunately not. The only thing I found useful is to do clang-format off and on again in imortant sections, but it's quiet a bad workaround

Answer (score 12):

> ReflowComments: (`bool`)
>
> If `true`, `clang-format` will attempt to re-flow comments.
>
> ```
> false:
> // veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment with plenty of information
> /* second veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment with plenty of information */
>
> true:
> // veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment with plenty of
> // information
> /* second veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment with plenty of
>  * information */
> ```

[Source](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

Use `ReflowComments: true`, when enabled it will add 1 space after `//` and brake comments when reach limit.

You can use `PenaltyBreakComment` to adjust.
E.g. block braking lines `PenaltyBreakComment: 1000000000`

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't do the job. The comments will be kept untouched, but the code infront of them will be split, even if it does not exceed the margin.

Comment: I just edited the question, sorry. But actually the example code showed the desired behaviour even before the edit.

Answer (score 3):

A worked example of the penalties...

It's not complete optimal, but with `clang-format-14`, if you start with code like

```
QSqlDriver* driver() const;  // UNCERTAIN IF THIS IS OK to return the driver on the GUI thread, even if it lives in another
QString m_connection_name;  // written only in constructor; thread-safe access
```

then with

```
ReflowComments: false  # default is true for WebKit
PenaltyBreakComment: 300  # default
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0  # default
```

you get this sort of irritation:

```
QSqlDriver* driver(
) const;  // UNCERTAIN IF THIS IS OK to return the driver on the GUI thread, even if it lives in another
QString
    m_connection_name;  // written only in constructor; thread-safe access
```

Whereas with this

```
ReflowComments:  true
PenaltyBreakComment: 300
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 0
```

you get

```
QSqlDriver*
    driver() const;  // UNCERTAIN IF THIS IS OK to return the driver on the
                     // GUI thread, even if it lives in another
QString
    m_connection_name;  // written only in constructor; thread-safe access
```

and finally with

```
ReflowComments:  true
PenaltyBreakComment: 0  # modified; was 300
PenaltyBreakOpenParenthesis: 1  # modified; was 0
```

you get

```
QSqlDriver* driver() const;  // UNCERTAIN IF THIS IS OK to return the
                             // driver on the GUI thread, even if it lives
                             // in another
QString m_connection_name;  // written only in constructor; thread-safe
                            // access
```